# How to take the rows of a matrix and save them in a cell array with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

this is my question:

I have this matrix `A`:

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 NaN; 6 8 9];
```

And I want to make something like this:

```
[B] = somefuntion(A)
```

Where B will have the next information:

```
B={[1 2 3];[4 5 NaN];[6 8 9]};
```

I hope that you can help me, thanks by the way!.

Comment: Do you want `num2cell`? Or you really want every row as a cell element?

Comment: Check [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html)

Comment: @Divakar yeah just did `help mat2cell` and got that... deleted my comment but too late ^^

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your fast answers, but I need what I asked before, I mean, with a cell array. The options that you gave me, like "num2cell" set ALL the matrix "A" in a single cell array (1x1), not in a 3x1 cell array. And num2cell just gives to me every single value in a cell array.

Comment: @lisandrojim `mat2cell` is your rescue, read the documentation carefully.

Comment: You're absolutely right !!!, I'll going to answer my own question, but thanks to you @Divakar

Comment: @lisandrojim See the pleasure of finding out your own solution!!? It's eating fruits from your own garden! :) Please do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 NaN; 6 8 9];

C = mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1)),size(A,2))
```

Results:

```
C{1}=[ 1     2     3];
C{2}=[ 4     5   NaN];
C{3}=[ 6     8     9];
```

Comment: See if you can make it work for a general case when A is not a square matrix, something like `4x3` maybe.

Comment: That piece of code may works for any size of matrix.

Comment: That's right! +1 there. Also may I suggest using `size` instead of the messy `length`. So maybe you can replace `size(A,1)` with `length(A(:,1))`  and `size(A,2)` with `length(A(1,:))`? How does that look?

Comment: Awesome! You learnt something today! :) Also you can accept your answer, in case you didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a simple loop?

```
for i = 1:size(A,2);
    B{i} = A(i,:);
end
B = B';
```

Comment: No, that's the reason why I asked. I don't want to use a "for" because I'm using thousands of data in a matrix, and that will make inefficient the process.